# load when (1:5) in select with external inline view asks for bind variables

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

I don't find the switch to turn the binds of in SQL Developer:

I've created an csv file:

```
    declare  
       v_file utl_file.file_type;
    begin  
       v_file := utl_file.fopen('DATA_FILE_DIR', 'example2.csv', 'W');
       utl_file.put_line(v_file, 'colid|colstring|colnumber|coldate');  
       utl_file.put_line(v_file, '1|"nothing"|231.12|2019-01-03 23:43:32');
       utl_file.put_line(v_file, '2|"not more"|121|2020-10-05 14:33:15');
       utl_file.FFLUSH(v_file);  
       utl_file.fclose(v_file);  
    end;
```

Which I want to read with an inline select:

```
select c_001,c_002, c_003, c_004 from external
((   c_001 varchar2(200)
   , c_002 varchar2(200)
   , c_003 varchar2(200)
   , c_004 varchar2(200)
     )
    TYPE oracle_loader
    default directory DATA_FILE_DIR
    access parameters (
         RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
         load when (1:5) != 'colid'
         LOGFILE DATA_FILE_DIR:'inline_ext_tab_%a_%p.log'
         FIELDS CSV WITH EMBEDDED TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
         MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL(
             c_001
           , c_002
           , c_003 
           , c_004 
         )
    )
    location ('example2.csv')
    reject limit unlimited
    )
```

Issue I get is `load when (1:5) != 'colid'` is asking for Bind substitution.

```
set define off;
set escape off;
```

didn't help in my case. Any ideas to prevent this behavior? 
Using skip 1 is because of Bug 29420254 no option.

Regression Bug 29420254 with `load when text != 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'` instead of `skip 1`:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-30653: reject limit reached

select filename,text
from external(( FILENAME VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),text VARCHAR2(10 CHAR))
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY "DATA_FILE_DIR"
ACCESS PARAMETERS
( RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
preprocessor DATA_FILE_DIR:'add_filename_semikolon.sh'
load when text != 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
(
FILENAME CHAR(255),
text CHAR (10)))
LOCATION
( 'Testfall_s1.csv')
);
```

Testfall_s1.csv:

```
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"abcd"
```

add_filename_semikolon.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Separator: ;
FILENAME='"'${1##*/}'"'
/usr/bin/sed -e 's/^/'$FILENAME';/' $1
```

But when reevaluating the bug (where patches are available, but don't want to patch every VM ...) I've missed a important requirement `preprocessor` which I currently don't use ...

Comment: Presumably you're using Oracle 18c or higher to be able to do this at all; which version of SQL Developer are you using (in case an older version doesn't recognise it)? As you're using strings everywhere at the moment you could possibly do `load when c_001 != 'colid'` - but perhaps you intend to change the column definition to number?

Comment: Yes I use 19c (19.3) and upgraded SQL Developer to 19.4 this morning (19.2 had the same issue). Will evaluate `c_001` != 'colid' vs 29420254

Comment: Seems to be a bug (or at least an oversight) in SQL Developer then. The product manager visits sometimes, but might be worth raising as a support issue, or at least asking on the [Oracle forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/database/developer-tools/sql_developer), if it hasn't come up there before - I can't see anything similar from a quick search.

Comment: At least in sqlplus, "load when c_001!='colid'" works. (I deleted my irrelevant answer, pertaining to substitution var and not bind). You can also add the condition in the where clause (as you have reject unlimited, the result will be the same)

Comment: Opened SR 3-22386132711 because if using fixed width `nbr (1:3) CHAR(3)` the issue also occurs.